# How to get text response directly on Dialogflow?

Tags: python, dialogflow-es, chatbot

I'm trying to get a direct text response from dialogflow. I do get an answer from the example code on github, but thats not user-friendly at all. How can I get the "Speech-Only" response?

```
import os.path
import sys

try:
    import apiai
except ImportError:
    sys.path.append(
        os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), os.pardir)
    )
    import apiai

CLIENT_ACCESS_TOKEN = 'YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN'


def main():
    ai = apiai.ApiAI(CLIENT_ACCESS_TOKEN)

    request = ai.text_request()

    request.lang = 'de'  # optional, default value equal 'en'

    request.session_id = "<SESSION ID, UNIQUE FOR EACH USER>"

    request.query = "Hello"

    response = request.getresponse()

    print (response.read())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I just expect a a simple result. A plain hello text.

What I get instead = `b'{\n  "id": "306fd06a-d9e6-4c2e-8c05-98ff7fc0ecd5",\n  "timestamp": "2017-12-05T22:18:15.563Z",\n  "lang": "en",\n  "result": {\n    "source": "agent",\n    "resolvedQuery": "hi",\n    "action": "input.welcome",\n    "actionIncomplete": false,\n    "parameters": {},\n    "contexts": [],\n    "metadata": {\n      "intentId": "8406ea3a-a0c9-4470-829f-aba0ce2da2e5",\n      "webhookUsed": "false",\n      "webhookForSlotFillingUsed": "false",\n      "intentName": "Default Welcome Intent"\n    },\n    "fulfillment": {\n      "speech": "Hi there!",\n      "messages": [\n        {\n          "type": 0,\n          "speech": "Hi there!"\n        }\n      ]\n    },\n    "score": 1.0\n  },\n  "alternateResult": {\n    "source": "domains",\n    "resolvedQuery": "hi",\n    "action": "smalltalk.greetings.hello",\n    "actionIncomplete": false,\n    "parameters": {},\n    "contexts": [],\n    "metadata": {},\n    "fulfillment": {\n      "speech": "Hey!",\n      "source": "agent"\n    },\n    "score": 1.0\n  },\n  "status": {\n    "code": 200,\n    "errorType": "success",\n    "webhookTimedOut": false\n  },\n  "sessionId": "mr.9000"\n}'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try like this to get the message:

```
response = json.loads(request.getresponse().read().decode('utf-8'))
message = response['result']['fulfillment']['speech']
print (message)
```

Don't forget to add

```
import json
```

at the beginning. If you haven't installed it yet, install it. You'll have to if you want to deal with json in python.
Tell me if it works

Comment: TypeError: 'HTTPResponse' object is not subscriptable. I wish it worked.

Comment: name 'json' is not defined. I feel we are close somehow.

Comment: Oh that's easy. just _improt json_ . If its not installed, pip install it.

Comment: how is everything # my input.
how is everything # The response is the exact thing i write.

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: I think instead of calling 'resolvedQuery',  we should print 'speech' which is inside of 'fulfillment'. OKAY! I went with message = response['result']['fulfillment']['speech'] and I do get the speech answer right away! <33

Comment: Thank you for accepting the answer! I've updated the answer to show the same so that others can refer it. :D

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using [Dialogflow's query API](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/agent/query). The format of the response is documented [here](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/agent/query#get_and_post_responses).  You'll have to parse the JSON.  The most common way to do this would be ...

1. Use the `json` module which you'll need to import (i.e. `import json` at the top of you file).
2. Next you'll need to load the JSON string you're received with the load method (i.e. add a line after you define `response`: `response_dict = json.loads(response.read())`
3. Lastly you'll need to retrieve the correct string from the `response_dict` object: `print(response_dict.['result']['resolvedQuery'])`